# Detect if xll is permanently installed or if xll files was just adhoc opened?

Tags: c#, excel-addins, excel-dna, netoffice

I'm building an addin for Excel using ExcelDna and NetOffice.

An addin in Excel can either be installed and included in every Excel session or it can be opened adhoc by just opening the xll file.

Is there any way for me to programmatically detect in my addin code whether it was opened adhoc or if it was installed?

Comment: isnt there any registryentry if it's "installed"?

Comment: @Niels Bosma: Did you find a reliable way to detect if the xll is being adhoc opened? Out of curiosity, why is (or was) that important in your scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the directory returned via `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` could tell you the answer, based on the installation folder.

Comment: No that wont work as the plugin doesn't have to be moved to Excel addin dir.